# Managing access to KMS key to be used only a lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, aws-lambda, amazon-kms

I have a use case where a kms key would be used to encrypt and decrypt data . how can I make sure that only the specific lambda should be able to use the kms key  from AWS polices .

I tried adding Lambda ARN in kms key policies while creating, but looks like its not allowed to do the same .

how can I achieve my use case ?

Comment: You would need to grant permission to the IAM Role used by the Lambda function, rather than the function itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. Create an IAM Role for Lambda without any permissions attached.
2. Select the same for `Define key usage permissions` while creating the key.
3. Attach the IAM Role to the Lambda.
4. Start using the KMS Key in the Lambda.

As per the AWS KMS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policies.html)

> The default key policy that the console creates for symmetric CMKs allows you to choose IAM users and roles in the account, and external AWS accounts, and make them key users.

Comment: I followed what u mentioned . I create a  blank lambda role  . and created key with key usage permission and gave lambda role . but I was able to encrypt data using another lambda using different lambda role say testRole2 . which should not have access to invoke kms .

Comment: Check the policies attached to testRole2?